# css selector trouble - next sibling

Tags: css

I'm looking for a css selector that selects elements of a class who's immediate successor (if there is one) does **not** have that class.

So lets say I have a div:

```
<div>
    <span id="1" class="myClass1">
    <span id="2">
    <span id="3" class="myClass1">
    <span id="4" class="myClass1">
    <span id="5">
</div>
```

This selector would grab spans 1 and 4.

Is this possible without javascript?

Comment: “*Is this possible without javascript?*” - no, CSS has no previous sibling selector.

Answer (score 1):

Try this selector:

```
span + span:not(.myClass1) {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

This is the adjacent sibling selector, coupled with the `not()` selector.

Comment: But OP wants to select the preceding sibling based on the class of the subsequent sibling.